# How to pass value from _layout to controller asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, layout, controller

I have this button in my layout that changes value with a click event:

```
<input type="button" id="switchbutton" value="Weekend" style="color:blue" onclick="toggle(this);">
                                <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                                <script>
                                    function toggle(button) {
                                        switch (button.value) {
                                        case "Weekend":
                                            button.value = "Week";
                                            break;
                                        case "Week":
                                            button.value = "Weekend";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        return value;
                                    }
                                </script>
```

And I need to send the value of the button to my controller to use it on a condition:

```
if (Button.value =="Weekend")
{
Do something
}
else
{
Do antoher thing
}
```

Could you please help me to send the value from the button on my layout to my controller?

Comment: In MVC you need to use old forms mechanism or you may want to send an AJAX request for this purpose.

Comment: Could you give me an example of something functional?

Comment: @pedrolopez That's really too broad. You know how to do an MVC form post? Then do that. Do you know how to do an AJAX request? Then do that. If you don't know either, then research!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the value similar to the view, on your form post.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "switchbutton")] YourModel yourModel){
string myValue = yourModel.switchbutton;}
```